# Capture event onclose browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

How I can capture event, close browser window, in jQuery or javascript ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Browser window close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the onclose event.

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onclose

note that not all browsers support this (for example firefox 2)

Comment: it does not work in many browsers. but that is the only event for the closing of a browser window

Comment: This is not good enough. The only working solution is [Browser window close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event#1632004)

Comment: Sorry, the page /en-US/DOM/window.onclose could not be found.

Answer (score 16):

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unload#fn

jQuery:

```
$(window).unload( function () { alert("Bye now!"); } );
```

or javascript:

```
window.onunload = function(){alert("Bye now!");}
```

Comment: this event work and when I do refresh, but i need, only when I close the browser!

Comment: @Alexander Corotchi: Why do you want to know when the user closes the browser?

Comment: In my application can work more users, And when 1 user close browser a need to execute a function for exclude this user from this application.

Comment: This is not good enough. The only working solution is [Browser window close event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event#1632004)

Comment: Fail, when page change url call unload event, but no only close. unload != close.

Answer (score 3):

Events onunload or onbeforeunload you can't use directly - they do not differ between window close, page refresh, form submit, link click or url change.

The only working solution is [How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event#1632004)

Comment: Spamming your answer across the comments and then it turns out to be a link-only answer....

Answer (score -1):

Men, use this:

```
if(myWindow.closed){
    callback();
    return;
}
```

Comment: This isn't "capturing"