# How to create popup window when browser close

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I want to open popup window when browser closed or closed tabs.

Comment: you can use window.onUnLoad function of javascript

Comment: when page refresh it's also called

Comment: try window.onclose(); https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onclose

Comment: Please don't do this, though. It's one of the easiest ways to annoy your users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
window.onUnLoad= function (evt) { 
 //your code goes here
 window.open("yourpage/some link");
}
```

EDIT NOTE: Now it will be called on onUnload event of browser. Try now

Try window.onclose event:

[Capture event onclose browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025935/capture-event-onclose-browser)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onclose

[How to capture the browser window close event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

References:

http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-function-in-javascript-before.html

On below like you can find all events with example of window for javascript:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0380__Window/windowonUnLoad.htm

Comment: this function also called when page refresh that is the problem

Comment: @Pradeep: actually i created this function to ask user before closing browser that are u really want to close browser. let me modify it.