# How to delete cookie when window closed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have some current_user method, which takes ID from cookie's `auth_token`, and I want cookie be to deleted when window with site has been closed.

```
 cookies[:auth_token] = @user.auth_token
```

What I have to add?

Comment: Look for [event that fires when browser window is closed or user navigates away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025935/capture-event-onclose-browser) and [update expiration date of your cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144386/javascript-delete-cookie) in that event handler.

Comment: So it is done through JS? No build-in Rails feature? Than what difference between `cookies` and `cookies.permanent`?

Comment: Didn't notice the ruby-on-rails tag at first. I'm not very proficient with Rails (more of a Django guy). Since cookies are saved in user's browser, you certainly can deal with them on client side from JS. It might be more convenient to do from Rails, but then you'd have to make an AJAX request from ``beforeunload`` handler in JS to get new response from Rails with updated cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you set a cookie without giving an expiration date, it
is only retained until the browser is closed.  (Which can mean the
program itself, not just a window or a tab.)

An expiration in the past will delete the cookie immediately.

From Thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/94682

@Joe Half Face, If it helps you, please mark it useful.

Comment: it works, but I don't know if idea of setting cookie expired from beginning is good? P.S. I don't want to follow user activity when they logged off

Comment: No, it deletes cookie immediantly, I found out... Guy gave wrong answer. Even hitting reload kicks your out to login page

Answer (score 0):

I once implemented a similar thing. For security purposes we had to automatically log the user out when they navigate away from the page. The solution looked like this:

- On client side, write a `beforeunload` event handler.
- From that handler make an AJAX request to logout URL, in your case it might be a special view that deletes the cookie (see [Rails docs on cookies](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html)).
- The AJAX request has to be synchronous to make sure `beforeunload` event handler waits for its completion.