# Opening another window in Javascript when user presses X on browser

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I understand this question has been asked and either answered or rejected before, but i promise i have a reasonably legit reason for asking. I am doing a Uni course and one of the requirements for the web app we are making is to have a certain page (daily sales report) open once the user presses X on the browser, this is a local file only ans aside from using `window.onbeforeunload = window.open("dailyreport.html");` , which opens the page every time I do anything (click links etc) I have hit a brick wall.

Also i forgot to mention we are not allowd to use JSON or jquery at all... sucks but thats what the bosses want

Thanks guys
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the `windown.onclose` event.

As from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025935/capture-event-onclose-browser)

However, note that this is not supported by all browsers. If it is for a uni project you might be able to get away with it though if your requirements don't specify across-the-board browser compatibility.

Comment: well i hope they dont, i have written this page using chrome and created a redirect page for all other browsers saying Unsupported, please download Chrome!"
I will have a try with this and let you know, thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zGK84/1/)

```
window.onload = function(){
        var as = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var linkClicked = false;
    for(i=0;i<as.length; i++){
        as[i].onclick = function(){

            linkClicked= true;
        }
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function(){!linkClicked && window.open("dailyreport.html");}
}
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick reply, while that does open a new window, it still opens it if i click any links within the page as well, not when it closes. Thanks though

Comment: @user2397654 as far as I know there is no way to differentiate between navigation and page close.

Comment: in that case, would i be able to have an event come up that displays all the data in the other page? I understand i would need to link to the data which is nothing to major, just time consuming, but can event windows handle any data? I figured having the info in a confirmation window would be sufficient

Comment: @user2397654 now I am preventing window.open on link click. try this

Comment: that has stopped the window from opening when i click links, but still nothing when i close the window/tab, does the location of the script matter?

Comment: @user2397654 It is working for me. do your all pages has this code. I mean after click on link browser will load new page. does new page has this code?

Comment: yeah it shows up in my code, i put it in the header. It doesnt seem to be doing anything that i can see, if i close the window it just closes, no popup warnings, nothing at all.

Comment: are you overriding window.onload function?

Comment: no nothing like that, does it make a difference that i am using chrome?